# C# WinForms - Overlay with Text Recognition and adding Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, overlay, text-recognition

in the current project im working on is to create a Dashboard based on the selected customer in a seperate Application. But it doesnt have much support regarding API or third party development.

My Goal is to create within an transparent overlay, marking an area which can either be read its content (Text) or a button be inserted for the user to interact.

I found a German Document Management System (DMS) provider online, facing a similar challenge. They need to extract data from a third-party application (ERP system) via parameters and pass it to their software. Below is a video so you can see what I mean.

https://youtu.be/nDs34rJi5co

I would like to use the correct terms of the corresponding subjects. But I can only vaguely describe and share the video which exactly does what I need to implement.

My current approaches:

- First Approach: Transparent Background Application, DrawRectange for rough position. (this approach wasnt throguhly planned/thought)
- Second Approach: Making a screenshot for text recognition and note the position of marked areas. But you wouldnt be able to interact with the application at the same time.

Comment: Is the text is selectable? if so you might just want to make it easier for the user to copy-paste the text. If not, you could probably use the accessibility APIs to extract text directly from another application. You should not have to resort to text recognition.

Comment: The Text should not be selectable. The above mentioned video shows everything the application should do. And I think the Accessibility API might the the right first step.